# Kill job if execution time less than 2 min

Tags: control-m

I have a chain with several jobs, and sometimes a certain job that normally takes about 2 hours, finishes in less than 2 minutes.

What I would like to do is to kill this job if it ends in less than 2 minutes so that the chain won't proceed.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: How do you know it's going to take less than two minutes?

Comment: i don't know why sometimes this happens i just want to kill the job if that happens

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't really want to kill anything, do you? If you do, see BMC's note (including video) on using **ctmkilljob**.

In this case your next job is dependent on 2 things, the predecessor job being ok and the duration of the predecessor job. Add another input condition to your next job (in addition to the existing condition) to represent the >2 minutes duration.

On the job that needs to run for more than 2 minutes, add a **Notify** when the Exectime exceeds 2 mins (or 60 mins or whatever you decide is the threshold) and get it to **shout** to an entry in your shout destination table.

On the Control-M Server create a new program entry in your **shout destination table** and create a small script referenced by the shout. The script should use the **ctmcontb** utility to create a new ODAT condition that your next is waiting on. If  you have a look at the BMC help note for ctmkilljob (and just substitute in ctmcontb) then you'll see how to do this.